# OpenVPN клиент не подключается на Windows 10

Tags: windows, сеть, windows-10, vpn, openvpn

Ответ поискал и не нашел.

Дано: машина с ubuntu, на которой поднят и удачно работает с десятком клиентов OpenVPN сервер по протоколу UDP.

Конфиги всех клиентов одинаковые, один раз написаны и откопированы. Разные только пачки сертификатов.

Подключается к серверу со всех клиентов, кроме домашнего Windows 10. Дома также есть отдельная машина с ubuntu в качестве тестового сервера и она тоже удачно коннектится к серверу, поэтому влияние провайдера исключено.

Что может быть не так в Win 10? Фаервол стандартный отрубал полностью, не помогло. Ничего нештатного для контроля сети не установлено.

Лог подключения:

```
Tue Jul 31 21:09:34 2018 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Tue Jul 31 21:09:34 2018 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Tue Jul 31 21:09:34 2018 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]
Tue Jul 31 21:09:34 2018 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]*SERVER*:*PORT*
Tue Jul 31 21:09:34 2018 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1533060574,WAIT,,,
```

В логе сервера подключение тоже светится:

```
Tue Jul 31 21:10:35 2018 *SERT*/*MyIP*:*PORT* TLS: new session incoming connection from [AF_INET]*MyIP*:*PORT*
Tue Jul 31 21:10:35 2018 *SERT*/*MyIP*:*PORT* TLS: new session incoming connection from [AF_INET]*MyIP*:*PORT*
Tue Jul 31 21:10:37 2018 *SERT*/*MyIP*:*PORT* VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=RU, ST=MO, L=MosFranciska, O=Neuros, OU=OU_e, CN=*SERT CA*, name=VPNs, emailAddress=Email
Tue Jul 31 21:10:37 2018 *SERT*/*MyIP*:*PORT* VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=RU, ST=MO, L=MosFranciska, O=Neuros, OU=OU_e, CN=*SERT*, name=VPNs, emailAddress=Email
Tue Jul 31 21:10:37 2018 *SERT*/*MyIP*:*PORT* Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Tue Jul 31 21:10:37 2018 *SERT*/*MyIP*:*PORT* Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Jul 31 21:10:37 2018 *SERT*/*MyIP*:*PORT* Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Tue Jul 31 21:10:37 2018 *SERT*/*MyIP*:*PORT* Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Jul 31 21:10:37 2018 *SERT*/*MyIP*:*PORT* TLS: move_session: dest=TM_ACTIVE src=TM_UNTRUSTED reinit_src=1
Tue Jul 31 21:10:37 2018 *SERT*/*MyIP*:*PORT* TLS: tls_multi_process: untrusted session promoted to semi-trusted
Tue Jul 31 21:10:37 2018 *SERT*/*MyIP*:*PORT* Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
Tue Jul 31 21:10:37 2018 *SERT*/*MyIP*:*PORT* TLS: new session incoming connection from [AF_INET]*MyIP*:*PORT*
Tue Jul 31 21:10:37 2018 *SERT*/*MyIP*:*PORT* TLS: new session incoming connection from [AF_INET]*MyIP*:*PORT*
Tue Jul 31 21:10:39 2018 *SERT*/*MyIP*:*PORT* VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=RU, ST=MO, L=MosFranciska, O=Neuros, OU=OU_e, CN=*SERT CA*, name=VPNs, emailAddress=Email
Tue Jul 31 21:10:39 2018 *SERT*/*MyIP*:*PORT* VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=RU, ST=MO, L=MosFranciska, O=Neuros, OU=OU_e, CN=*SERT*, name=VPNs, emailAddress=Email
Tue Jul 31 21:10:39 2018 *SERT*/*MyIP*:*PORT* Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Tue Jul 31 21:10:39 2018 *SERT*/*MyIP*:*PORT* Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Jul 31 21:10:39 2018 *SERT*/*MyIP*:*PORT* Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Tue Jul 31 21:10:39 2018 *SERT*/*MyIP*:*PORT* Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Jul 31 21:10:39 2018 *SERT*/*MyIP*:*PORT* TLS: move_session: dest=TM_ACTIVE src=TM_UNTRUSTED reinit_src=1
Tue Jul 31 21:10:39 2018 *SERT*/*MyIP*:*PORT* NOTE: --mute triggered...
```

TLS отключен везде.
Раньше винда удачно подключалась, потом был перерыв(не пользовался из дома этим VPN), а потом накатилось очередное обновление винды и работать перестало.

Comment: Опытным путем и мониторингом трафика стало ясно, что UDP пакеты от хоста на сервер улетают, а ответные пакеты от сервера не прилетают. И это только на Win10 устройствах, которые обновились в июле.

Answer (score 1):

Помогло удаление и новая установка TAP-Windows файлами из папки bin.